# MySQL Running Total

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores amounts and interest rates which looks like so. These are effectively bids, or offers of lending on a loan on a simple system I am building. If there is a loan of £1000000, there can be multiple offers/bids for this loan.

I need these bids to be sorted on best interest rate, this I can do. However I cannot keep a running total to track which bids are acceptable.

Here is the table I have.

```
+-----+--------+---------------+------------+
| id  | amount | interest_rate | aggregated |
+-----+--------+---------------+------------+
| 105 | 100000 | 5             |     100000 |
| 108 | 500000 | 6.75          |     600000 |
| 107 |  50000 | 7             |     650000 |
| 106 | 100000 | 8             |     750000 |
| 112 | 500000 | 8.75          |    1250000 |
| 111 |   5000 | 16            |    1255000 |
| 110 | 500000 | 20            |    1755000 |
+-----+--------+---------------+------------+
```

Here you can see that I have managed to get an aggregated column. However I need to get all bids that fall under the £1000000, meaning if I use the aggregated column, it only returns the top four.

To give you a better idea, here is the table again with the desired returned results that I require.

```
+-----+--------+---------------+------------+--------+--------+
| id  | amount | interest_rate | aggregated | wanted | total  |
+-----+--------+---------------+------------+--------+--------+
| 105 | 100000 | 5             |     100000 | *      | 100000 |
| 108 | 500000 | 6.75          |     600000 | *      | 600000 |
| 107 |  50000 | 7             |     650000 | *      | 650000 |
| 106 | 100000 | 8             |     750000 | *      | 750000 |
| 112 | 500000 | 8.75          |    1250000 |        | 750000 |
| 111 |   5000 | 16            |    1255000 | *      | 755000 |
| 110 | 500000 | 20            |    1755000 |        | 755000 |
+-----+--------+---------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

Basically I want to select all rows sorted by interest_rate that fits under 1000000. You can see here we have skipped row 112 because 750000 + 1250000 > 1000000, therefore we skip it and move on.

Here is the simple SQL I am currently using to return these results.

```
SET @aggregated = 0;
SET @position = 0;
SELECT id, amount, interest_rate, aggregated FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        @aggregated := @aggregated + `auction_bids`.`amount` as `aggregated`,
        @position := @position + 1 as `position`        
    FROM 
        `auction_bids` 
    WHERE 
        `auction_bids`.`auction_id` = 21 AND
        `auction_bids`.`amount` < 1000000
    ORDER BY 
        `auction_bids`.`interest_rate` ASC
) as `a`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help, although it goes wrong when I try and use it in a nested query on SQLFiddle:

```
set @aggregated := 0;
set @position := 0;
set @inc := 0;

select
    *,
    @aggregated := @aggregated + `auction_bids`.`amount` as `aggregated`,
    @position := @position + 1 as `position`,
    case 
        when @inc + `auction_bids`.`amount` <= 1000000 then 1
        else 0 
    end as `wanted`,
    @inc := @inc + case 
        when @inc + `auction_bids`.`amount` > 1000000 then 0 
        else `auction_bids`.`amount` 
    end as `includedaggregate`
from
    `auction_bids` 
where 
    `auction_bids`.`auction_id` = 21 and
    `auction_bids`.`amount` < 1000000
order by
    `auction_bids`.`interest_rate`
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff9f8/11)</kbd>**

Comment: This is brilliant, I've spent weeks scratching my head with this one. Thank you. I didn't have any issues running this in a nested query.